# xCode Collapse Node on jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, xcode, function

I am trying to better navigate my JS files in XCode and I can collapse traditional function(){} calls by using Cmd+Alt+Shift+Left but this does not collapse jQuery .on click function calls.

Is it possible to also collapse jQuery functions for easier viewability?

If not, is there a way to possibly rewrite the functions to fool xCode into collapsing them?  Write now these functions look like:

```
$(document).on('click','#id',function(e) {
    //some code here
});
```

Thanks!